# ¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo que random.randint pero con números reales?

Tags: python-3.x, random

Quisiera crear una lista con 100 números reales aleatorios que estén entre el -10 y el 10.
Si los números fuesen enteros, se que tengo que hacerlo con random.randint, pero en este caso, como tendría que hacerlo?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
random.random() * 20 - 10
```

random.random() genera números entre 0.0 y 1.0, al multiplicarlo por 20, esto pasa a generar números entre 0.0 y 20.0, y al restar 10, genera números entre -10.0 y 10.0

Comment: No se me había ocurrido, gracias!